# Django - Overriding labels is not working with forms ChoiceField

Tags: django

I found a workaround to this problem, but I'm asking it anyways because it was quite odd.

I have a model field called `agent_title` under model `Agent`.  I want to display it on my form as just `Title`.  I need to display the field with ChoiceField.  However when I modify the field to be a ChoiceField, the label override stops working.  Any reasons why?

**This works...**

```
class AgentInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        labels = {
            'agent_title': 'Title',
        }
```

---

**But this doesn't**

```
class AgentInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    agent_title = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AGENT_TITLE)
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        labels = {
            'agent_title': 'Title',
        }
```

Comment: This is the same as the question I answered earlier today. You are trying to override the label instead of the widget, but it doesn't work for the exact same reason. See the Note in the docs for [overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) for a full explanation.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are right.  I'm getting a better understanding of forms now, thanks.